# printer and print dialog

Tags: c#

I would like to print a file but I don't want to see the print Dialog appear each time I press Ctrl+P, I would like it to print the file I specify once I choose the Print button on my form. Is there any possible way to achieve this ? [I will set up all things: page size, color, printer  print my document etc those of whose properties I get to display on my form.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the PrintVisual() method of PrintDialog():

```
new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog().PrintVisual(this.yourVisual, "Description");
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking out the [`StandardPrintController` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.standardprintcontroller.aspx) on MSDN.